# Which eloquent relationship should I use?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a table 'words' and a table 'categories'. Each category named by a letter. I need to list all categories and below each category show words that belong to that category. A word cant belong to many categories meanwhile a category can have many words.
Which relationship should I use to implement that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy and you guessed it since you said it yourself:

*A word belong to one category, and a category has many words.*

You need a [One To Many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many).

(This means `Words` can only have one `Category`. If you needed Word to have many Categories, you would instead use a Many To Many relationship.)

---

To answer your comment, you can do the following in a view to list the names of all words in a specific category:

```html
@foreach ($category->words as $word)
    {{ $word->name }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: With that kind of relationship a following error occurs: Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance. Code that triggered that error: {{$category->words->name}}
I know it fails because the code above return a collection. {{$category->words->get(0)->name}} works fine. But thats not what I need

Comment: @WaldemarKarasik Yes, because `$category->words` return many `Words` but you are trying to access the property `->name` of a single object on a collection. You cannot access `->name` on a collection of multiple object, you need to call it on a single object of type `Word`.

Comment: @WaldemarKarasik I edited my answer to show you how to list all names from a collection of words.

Comment: So how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

As LobsterBaz pointed out, you would use a One to Many relationship. For example, for your category model

```
class Category extends Model
{
    public function words()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Word'); 
        // A category can have many words associated with it
    }
}
```

Knowing this, we can access all the words given a category, for example, the category with ID 1

```
 Category::find(1)->words()->get();
```

We can also define the inverse of this relationship

```
class Word extends Model
{
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category'); 
        // A word belongs to a category
    }
}
```

Knowing this, we can access the category of a given word, for example, the word with ID 1

```
Word::find(1)->category()->get();
```